# Is there a way to tell in which direction a London Tube train will pass the station platform?

Tags: public-transport, london, tfl

Many [transit apps](https://www.engadget.com/2015/08/24/citymapper-app-best-place-train/) and websites provide information on the optimal Tube train section

[image]

or carriage

[image]

to enter as part of journey planning.

But in order to make use of this information (unless one wants to risk running along a busy platform through gathering crowds as the train arrives), one needs to know from what direction a Tube train will pass the station platform.

Is there a general way, while standing on a platform, to determine — perhaps from subtle signage clues, or track arrangements, or even something about the infrastructure of the platform — from which direction a Tube train, especially a deep tube train, will pass the station platform? Is there a way to anticipate (other than an announcement) the sequel while riding on a train: on what side the doors will open?

Comment: Most trains have a fixed side of the track they are using, if it is a double track line. Now you only have to work out whether it is a middle platform or one of two outside platforms.

Comment: You are quite fastidious concerning answers....

Comment: @Willeke: None of that is reliably that easy to determine on the deep tube. Again, it's not about working out in one's head the structure of the platforms (which can be quite disorienting deep underground) but whether once at the platform there are reliable clues.

Comment: @GayotFow: What's the "getting out map"? It sounds interesting. But it probably still misses the mark: the goal is to not have to use an additional reference document, but to be able to see something on the platform (ideally in passing and not requiring an additional step like referring to an app or website).

Comment: Would the following work?  Use a map to determine which direction the line runs through the station, e.g. northwest to southeast.  A standard Tube map won't show this well, but the transit overlay in Apple or Google maps seems to usually be pretty accurate.  Then use a compass, or the electronic compass on your smartphone, to determine which direction is which.

Comment: I've noticed that some tube platforms have notice boards for the driver at the front end. I've never checked whether all of them do and if these are only at one end.

Comment: Bad user interface is bad. "Front" or "back" of the train means nothing to the user, they should have written "go left/right when you are at the platform" instead.

Comment: *It seems that there is no reliable way to accomplish this from clues on the platform. But [there is](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91710/1607) a [comprehensive reference](http://carto.metro.free.fr/metro-london/) available. To suggest using this reference to add the missing info to the apps mentioned on the OP: [Citymapper](https://citymapper.com/contact/support), [Tube Map](https://www.mapway.com/contact-us/). Send a link the [track map](http://carto.metro.free.fr/metro-london/) and suggest that they use it to determine direction.*

Comment: Although it only gives a short amount of notice, you can feel the air being pushed into the platform when the train is getting close. If you feel a gust of wind coming from the left, then the train is approaching that way. If you feel a gust of wind from the right, it's coming from the right.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni there are a few stations with odd/multiple arrangements of stairs/escalators/lifts.  This field would need to be populated by hand per platform.

Comment: @ChrisH If I understand correctly what you mean, it doesn't seem difficult to do for someone writing a timetable app. You do it once, and then it's correct almost forever.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni it's essentially impossible for someone writing an app. The information would have to be crowd-sourced given how many stations there are, and how many platforms at some stations.

Comment: @ChrisH: Isn't the information we're talking about already available in a [single document](http://carto.metro.free.fr/metro-london/) ([added](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/91688/revisions) to [the accepted answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/91688/1607))?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius no, because that map doesn't mark the direction the steps approach the platform.  "Turn left/right" doesn't make much sense when the steps are at the end of the platform, for example; "go to the far end" doesn't work if the steps are at one end and the lift at the other, etc.

Comment: @ChrisH: I think you're not correctly visualizing the information that's sought. It's not which way a *passenger* should turn when entering the platform, it's what direction the *train* passes the platform (to the left or to the right). That information is in the linked maps.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius no. I'm replying to *Bad user interface is bad. "Front" or "back" of the train means nothing to the user, they should have written "go left/right when you are at the platform" instead. – Federico Poloni*

Comment: @ChrisH: I was interpreting that to refer to where the front of the train is relative to the platform (at the left or right). If he means where the desired carriage is, then it is indeed nonsense.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For the most part, tube trains travel on the left. So, if you have a reference to the other platform, you can deduce in which direction the train will be travelling.

On a few of the older cut-and-cover lines, we have two tracks running down the middle with platforms on either side (*i.e.*, you can look across the tracks and see the other platform). For example, this is true at Monument, Sloane Square, Fulham Broadway, Cannon Street and many other stations on the Circle/District lines. Here the trains travel on the left.

At smaller, newer stations where there is only one line, the platforms are usually in the middle of the two tracks. Sometimes there is a single "island" platform (*e.g.,* South Kensington) but on the deeper lines the platforms are separated, in their own tunnels: either way, the principle still holds. Again the trains travel on the left, so you can use this to infer the front of the train.

At big stations where many lines intersect, it is harder to follow the principle; sometimes the trains switch sides or the platforms are optimized for connections between different lines. A close look at the [actual track and platform arrangements](http://carto.metro.free.fr/metro-london/) illustrates these patterns as well as some of the notable exceptions:

[image]

General rules:

- Trains run on the left
- Deep tube platforms are situated between tracks
- Sub-surface tube platforms are situated outside tracks

As a result, deep tube trains generally run to your right as you stand on the platform facing the tracks, while sub-surface trains run to your left.

Exceptions:

- Platforms are sometimes rearranged (e.g. Platform 2 at St. Paul's is outside the tracks rather than between as is generally the case for deep tube; Platform 1 at Mansion House is between rather than outside as is generally the case for sub surface lines; At Piccadilly Circus, Oxford Circus, and Embankment, both Bakerloo platforms are outside rather than between the tracks)
- Rarely, trains run on the right (e.g., the Northern line at Bank and at London Bridge).

As a result, deep tube trains sometimes run to your left (Bakerloo at Piccadilly Circus, Oxford Circus, and Embankment; eastbound Central trains at St. Paul's) and sub-surface trains sometimes run to your right (westbound Circle and District lines at Mansion House; Northern line at Bank and London Bridge).

At the platform you may be able to spot the the clear ("go") signal lights (white for deep lines, green for all other lines) located at the driver's end of the platform. This is probably only going to be illuminated when the train is already there, of course, but you may be able to see the light regardless.

In the end, once you do a journey quite often you will automatically find yourself going to the most optimal part of the train and it becomes second nature. If you are only doing it once, it probably is not so important.

Comment: The challenge consists of two parts: (1) for deep tube lines it's often not easy to determine which "side" the track you're looking at is on (2) exceptions such as the Northern line at Bank break simple rules.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius (1) For most deep lines you are in the middle. You'll notice that from the design as you come into the platform. (2) Look for the signal light.

Comment: Is there a list of exceptions for (1)? If its a short list, that might do the trick. Isn't the signal light hard to see from the platform (it is on the ones I've checked)?

Comment: This may be the answer, but if so I'm honestly kind of disappointed. I'd have thought that either TfL would provide some clever signage or subtle indicator of the train's travel direction (they do such an excellent job of conveying information in general) or that there would be some subtle but 100% reliable trick that transit nerds had uncovered (e.g. the placement of the third and fourth rails relative to the running rails).

Comment: It looks to me (from memory, I'm not in London today) like the the positive rail is usually on the left hand side in the direction of travel. If that's always reliably the case, then that would do the trick!

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Afraid not. The electrified rails can switch sides, so that the outer electrified rail is always furthest away from a platform edge.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think of it that's of course what's going on! (The positive one is the one outside the running pair.)

Comment: The northern line has some tricks when it comes to the side, because in addition to being on the right at bank, there is also oval where the northbound trains travel above the southbound trains, stockwell where northbound northern line trains are on the left of the station but right of the platform group, (the victoria line southbound has the same issue), and kennington where there are 4 tracks.

Comment: Also there are a couple of stations where the go light is not at the end of the platform, but sometimes up to one third of the length up the platform, so if you can't see it at the end, it may be further down.

Comment: Calchas, raxacoricofallapatorius has proposed an edit. Because it is quite massive (otherwise fine), me and another user are quite uncertain to accept it. Would you look at the edit? It can be seen under the edited link in the middle under the answer.

Comment: I've approved the edit since it seemed good. But please feel free to roll-back if it's not welcome.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and frankly you'd have every right to accuse me of undue pedantry for pointing this out, simply because I happen to really like underground signalling, but I really don't know where you read 'white for deep lines, green for all other lines'. Only the Central uses a white light as a signal aspect for the train driver, and even then it uses green as well, but green and white have different meanings. Both the Jubilee and Northern have ready to depart indicators for platform staff which are white,

Comment: but those indicators are placed irregularly and are hard to spot unless they're lit (and even then). They will only light up when the train is ready to go and it's possible the doors could already be closing by then. They will never be lit with no train in the platform. No other deep line uses white and the rest definitely use red/green, with the exception of the Victoria which uses red/blue (and green?), but you will only ever see red until the train is in the platform.

Comment: @Au101 I observe that the white lights in the tunnel platforms on my way to work (Victoria/Circle/Northern), didn't read about them anywhere. :) If they are platform indicators instead of signals, I'm happy amend my answer.

Comment: Also, whoever did edit my answer, I think that at St. Paul's the platforms are stacked one above one the other, not "outside the tracks".

Comment: Well if I could +1 you again, I would just for observation, but the only meaningful white lights on the platforms that spring to mind are these things on the Northern: https://www.flickr.com/photos/24772733@N05/5347207514/ I'm not sure what you're seeing on the Victoria or the Circle, but I'd be fascinated. The Victoria used to have white lights, but they went a few years ago. As for the circle i'm stumped! which platforms are you standing at?

Comment: @Au101 Never seen them on the Circle lines. I meant my way to work includes the Circle line, not that I had seen them there. I will check the Victoria line stations again next time I go to work, maybe I imagined them. ;) I get on at Pimlico.

Comment: @Calchas Ahhh =) Well certainly in the past I imagine you would have seen white signal lights at the departure end at Pimlico quite a lot, but I'm sure the signals were all changed a little while ago and I don't think they use white anymore. They did also used to show green on the Victoria line as well, but if you're mainly travelling at rush hour i guess the signal at pimlico probably wouldn't have had time to go green before the next train arrived :P Nowadays too I believe they show red blue and green, but the signals stay red until the train arrives anyway

Comment: @Au101 You are right, the platform indicators are only on the northern line. And I notice that much of the Victoria line is signalled in both direction, so this is less helpful.

Comment: @Calchas Could the reversal at the Northern line at Bank and at London Bridge have anything to do with the steep track running into the now disused (actually now repurposed) King William Street station? I know these tracks sloped up into the station at different grades and it would have been prudent to chose the more gradual sloping one as the inbound track. Was the more gradually sloping track on the right, by any chance?

Comment: @Calchas Also, doesn't the fact that deep tube platforms are situated between tracks
while sub-surface tube platforms are situated outside tracks mean that the fourth rails for deep tube are on the outside of the permanent way, while they are between tracks on sub surface lines?

Answer (score 35):

Look for the end of the platform with TV screens. These are at the front of the train in the direction of travel because the driver uses these screens to view when it is safe to close the doors.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't floated higher. This is the simplest way to tell, using the platform itself, with no fancy resources, and it's essentially universal. Other tube systems might swap the TVs for mirrors or whatnot, but platform ends in the direction of travel tend to have infrastructure for the train driver to monitor the platform.

Comment: This is *in theory* a good method, but those screens are situated on the edge of the platform and point towards the track, so they are hard to discern as a passenger standing on the platform.

Comment: The problem is that platform-mounted CCTV monitors and mirrors are on their way out, being replaced by in-cab CCTV equipment. The Central, Jubilee, Northern, Victoria and Waterloo & City lines all have no platform monitors and they are due to go very soon on the Circle, District, Hammersmith & City and Metropolitan lines just as soon as all of the old trains have gone, in fact, already the monitors on many Metropolitan platforms have been decommissioned if they've not been taken away already

Comment: Look at the scuff marks on the "mind the gap" paint too - you can often tell where the high foot-traffic doors are for a particular station by how worn the paint is. This is also an "insider" secret us Londoners use to know where the doors will open and enable us to stand in just the right spot... :-)

Comment: You can also look for the red/green light signal just inside the tunnel, which is obviously at the driver's end/ front of the train.

Comment: Once you have done the same journey for more than a month, you "just know" where you should wait for your train!

Comment: @nigel222: note that some platforms have a red signal at the rearwards end of the platform, so being able to see a red light isn't conclusive (but obviously seeing a green light is).

Answer (score 23):

Here's a some things an observant rider will see:

- Which direction are the local riders watching for the train.
- Which end of the platform has **White** (Victoria and Central) or **Green** (all other lines) **signal lights**.
- Which way are other trains going (you'll also have to note the type of platform Transfer and Local vs Express).  This is often useful on the Circle, District or Hammersmith & City Lines.
- From which direction is the breeze coming.

To know which side the doors will open will require either local knowledge/experience, or station maps.  MTA / New York City Subway has the station maps on their website.  I would expect (don't know though) London Transport to has the same.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57194/discussion-on-answer-by-johns-305-is-there-a-way-to-tell-in-which-direction-a-lo).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the breeze ... I've been out of London long enough now I forgot that one!

Answer (score 23):

Ask a station attendant (if there are any) or one or more people waiting.

Comment: Happy to upvote a legitimate answer.

Comment: Certainly the universal solvent for any sort of issue like this: *ask someone*.

Comment: The only correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

1. Look at a map to determine the cardinal direction of the track for your line in the direction of your destination.

   For instance, let's say you are at Aldgate waiting for the Circle Line anticlockwise toward Euston and Kings Cross.  The [standard tube map](https://tfl.gov.uk/maps/track/tube), which should be posted in the station, shows the line running north; but this map is only schematic and may not always be geographically accurate.  Standard online map apps, such as Apple Maps or Google Maps, have a [transit layer](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.5143415,-0.0759156,16.25z/data=!5m1!1e2) which shows transit lines overlaid on a street map, which show, with reasonable accuracy, where the lines actually run.  (If you don't expect to have mobile internet access underground, the Google Maps phone app at least will let you pre-download map tiles with the "Offline Areas" feature.)  This shows the line actually runs to the northeast.
2. If your smartphone is equipped with an electronic compass (for instance, recent iPhones have a Compass app), you can orient yourself in the appropriate direction.  Or you can carry a magnetic compass with you (though you might look a bit silly checking it).  Or, you can note your orientation (with respect to the streets) as you enter the station, and try to keep track as you turn corners within the station.

Comment: I was going to recommend Google Maps. Finding the closest angle towards the next station is usually enough to guess which direction a train is facing.

Comment: @Sumurai8: Google Maps is somewhat terrible for this, though. The base map does show the tunnels reasonably accurately as thin dashed grey lines -- but if you click on a transit icon you'll get a colored line overlay whose relation to reality (e.g. for Jubilee at Baker Street or Northern at Euston) can be tenuous.

Comment: It's a fantastic point, Nate, that - of course! - you can know this by *actually thinking of the direction involved!!*.  Brilliant.  (It's true that it's hard to get device location/compass working underground, but still it's a great point.)

Comment: @Fattie: Device location is hard to get working underground because it is usually based on GPS and needs to receive radio signals from space.  But the compass just detects the earth's magnetic field, like any other compass, and that should work fine underground.  See https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11557/will-a-compass-work-underground-or-underwater

Comment: hey Nate - that's an outstanding point!!!  I had never thought about whether ordinary magnetic compasses work underground - sure enough they do.  The compass in a phone is a Hall Effect device; I would imagine (but I don't know) they'd work underground or underwater as well as an old-days compass.

Comment: @NateEldredge this is the closest answer for me. I'm not sure why no-one has mentioned the signs that are on the platforms showing the current station as the starting point? Then you either know which station you want to go to or you look at a full tube map to determine the direction. All of these are available on station platforms. I travelled on the tube for 12 years and never used the tvs, the tracks, lights or anything apart from the signs and maps.

Answer (score 8):

While thinking about this question, I found a web site with diagrams of London Underground stations, [3D maps of every Underground station](https://www.ianvisits.co.uk/blog/2015/07/12/3d-maps-of-every-underground-station-ab/). Using this does require Internet access, not just on-the-platform observation.

For example, at [Tottenham Court Road](https://www.ianvisits.co.uk/blog/2015/07/12/3d-maps-of-every-underground-station-tuvw/) the front of the Eastbound Central Line trains is at the ticket hall end of platform 2. The platform is on the right side of the train, facing forwards.

Comment: But: *"while standing on a platform"*.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Whether the you will be able to access the Internet while standing on the platform depends on the your phone carrier, or the you can pay separately. See [Station WiFi](https://tfl.gov.uk/campaign/station-wifi). Alternatively, you could look up the platform information for your journey at the same time as getting the carriage recommendation.

Comment: Have you tried that? (Not really what I had in mind as a practical "on the platform" solution.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Tried which? I only became aware of the 3D maps web site while considering this question, and I am currently several thousand miles from the nearest tube station, so I cannot test that. If I remember correctly, I have used WiFi on station platforms, but that is highly dependent on cell phone carrier and plan.

Comment: WiFi is not dependent on cell carriers unless the transit company is getting internet access by cell (highly unlikely).

Comment: @WGroleau Do you have Transport for London specific information that supersedes or corrects the [Station WiFi](https://tfl.gov.uk/campaign/station-wifi) link I posted above? If that page is correct, station WiFi is being provided by cell phone companies for their customers, and those who pay for a pass.

Comment: Actually, I didn't see the first comment, just the second.  That's interesting to me.  Been in bus station, restaurants, train stations and airports claiming free WiFi in ten countries, but this is the first I ever heard of it being provided by a cell company.  I do suspect, though, that it's wired to the internet and not depending on a radio tower.

Comment: @WGroleau I'm sure it's wired, one way or another. Hampstead is one of the WiFi stations. Its platforms are 192 feet below ground level, connected to the ticket hall by elevators and a spiral staircase. Not good for radio signals.

Comment: It's possible (but I doubt it) that they could have a cell antenna above wired to an AP below.  But more likely wired direct to internet.

Answer (score 8):

The enthusiast map at http://carto.metro.free.fr/cartes/metro-tram-london/ shows, among other things, where the platforms are located relative to the tracks at each station.

Knowing that the trains usually run on the left (the exceptions are noted on the map too, notably Central Line at White City, Northern Line at London Bridge and Bank, and Victoria Line between Warren Street and St Pancras), this should enable you to predict which direction the train will go when you stand on the platform facing the train.

Comment: Yes, these are a great resource and I carry the latest as a PDF on my phone at all times (and an essential part of any transit nerds kit). I was hoping for something that works "on the platform" (i.e. from cues on the platform, without a reference) but it seems from what others have said that that's not possible. So having a resource like this is worth including among the answers.

Comment: I've suggested to the Citymapper folks (about a year ago) that they study this and use it to indicate the direction of trains as seen from the platform (it's just a few hours work at most). But they have other higher priority thing to do (adding cities to the app!) so: nothing yet. (If you join me in the suggestion, maybe they'll start to prioritize it.)

Comment: To suggest using this reference to add the missing info to the apps mentioned on the OP: [Citymapper](https://citymapper.com/contact/support), [Tube Map](https://www.mapway.com/contact-us/). Send a link the [track map](http://carto.metro.free.fr/metro-london/) and suggest that they use it to determine direction.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that surprisingly hasn't been mentioned; there's usually a [digital](http://citytransport.info/Digi/P1270341a.jpg) (or possibly sometimes analogue?) clock right at the end of the platform at which the front of the train stops.

[image]

In this photo the digital clock is above the blue box on the right.

Comment: @user568458 it's not my photo and I don't know what licence it's under, hence linking rather than uploading myself.

Comment: Oh, okay, feel free to revert the edit if you prefer

Comment: I don't know what the policy on copyrighted images is here.

Comment: This is a very nice observation, and a great answer. But you've been really really unfortunate with the image because it demonstrates one of the problems. That's a picture of Piccadilly Circus where trains can terminate and head back in the other direction using the points you can see in the picture. By poor fortune your picture shows the back of the platform. Almost all trains will arrive from the direction we're looking and depart in the other direction. Only very rarely will trains terminate and then head back in the direction we're looking

Comment: @Au101 Very good point - but then most of the other suggestions (besides the rules of thumb about train running side) have the same issue! Thanks for pointing out the picture's problem, though, I should really have noticed by the other train in the background that it was on the right!

Comment: They do indeed have the same problem, it's one of the things that put me off adding an answer, but yeah, it's a really unfortunate choice of illustration

Comment: I'll find something of my own, that'll solve the copyright issue too, in the next couple of days.

Comment: What platform (1 or 2) is that?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius 2

Comment: @Au101: Thanks! I realized only later that you'd already answered that ("all trains will arrive from the direction we're looking") but forgot to delete my comment! How often do trains reverse there?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius None are scheduled to the last time I looked. Possibly there's one i've overlooked that does the move in order to keep the equipment in order, keep drivers' route knowledge up etc. but otherwise none scheduled. As an emergency reversing point for when everything's all going horribly wrong, again, it's not common in my experience, but maybe I just don't look at the TfL website at the right moments :P Although, from 11/1996 - 06/1997 I hear the Bakerloo was suspended south of Piccadilly Circus for work on the tunnels under the Thames

Comment: @Au101: So basically just for emergencies. Do reversals occur with any frequency anywhere else. I'm wondering whether such cases warrant listing another exception in the accepted answer (for completeness): "In ultra-rare cases (emergencies or other extremities) trains reverse direction, switching to the opposite track just beyond the platform (e.g., the Bakerloo at Piccadilly Circus)".

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius At Piccadilly Circus basically just for emergencies yes. The trouble is there's no way of knowing which end is normally at the front and which one is normally at the back unless you already know :P As for other platforms where trains can depart in either direction from the same platform: it is unusual for this to be scheduled (except once/a few times a day to keep the equipment in good order etc. etc.) because, apart from anything else, the platform will get very busy if used for both arrivals and departures and the train will block the line while the driver swaps ends

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius But there are quite a good number of locations where trains quite often depart in the "wrong" direction during times of service disruption. Leytonstone's platform 2 is a classic example of this